# Joomla 3.2 intro page in html

Tags: html, joomla

I had an intro page namely index.html page in my Joomla 3.2 site. And this is the first page that show up. When I click to link to index.php there is no problem there. When I click home on index.php it goes back to the index.html page.

Now how can I avoid going back to index.html page. So if I click on menu home on the Joomla page it stays in index.php but index.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I assume you have the homepage menu item linking to an article or component of some sort. What you could do is make it an external link.

1. Open the menu item in the Menu Manager
2. Change the "type" to "External Link"
3. Enter the following link >> http://yoursite.com/index.php

Hope this helps

Comment: I got this error when following your instruction "Save failed with the following error: The home menu item must be a component."

Comment: it's throwing that error as it's currently your "default" menu item. Seeing as you have a index.html landing page, assign the default menu item to a different menu item

Comment: can you give an example pls